# Nginx ip_hash does not balance connections

Tags: nginx

I cannot get `nginx` to load balance with `ip_hash` enabled in `upstream` module. When I remove it load balancing works but I need sticky sessioning. What am I doing wrong?

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
     default upgrade;
     ''      close;
}

upstream backend {
    ip_hash;
    server localhost:3900 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=5s;
    server localhost:3901 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=5s;
}

# Only retry if there was a communication error, not a timeout.
proxy_next_upstream error;

server {
    server_name  localhost;
    listen 8300;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/myapp.access.log;

    # static file
    location /assets/ {
        root /location/to/statics/;
        autoindex off;
    }

    # sockjs
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was running all tests from one machine so all connecteions had the same IP address and were put to the same server due to sticky sessioning.